# java monitoring: Overhead of jconsole?

Tags: java, monitoring

I'm evaluating several java monitoring tools and I'd like to know what's the overhead when using `jconsole` (the main window) to monitor a process?
How much resources (`CPU`/`memory`) does it cost on the to-be-monitored process?

**Is it rather a development tool or can it be used in production?**

Answer (score 0):

This article https://weblogs.java.net/blog/emcmanus/archive/2006/07/how_much_does_i.html says remote monitoring of jconsole produces an overhead around 4%. Check the article to get your own conclusions.